# How to disable log output in Cordova apps

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Could you please tell me how to disable the logs output by the cordova plugin all together?

The logs output from the plugin are also output to the production app.
For Android, the logs are output to logcat, and for iOS, the logs are output to the console app, and we would like to disable them so that we can check the contents of the logs.

I tried with the release build but the logs are still being output, and logs are being output from plugins other than the one I created.